# Convert or format string to date

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I am struggling with this ..
I have an input string - like this:  2021-10-13 11:33:16.000-04

Using Java.

I need to get a Date object from it.
which formatting pattern can I use ?

I try with these

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'-'ZZ");
```

and

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
```

and I keep getting

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2021-10-13 11:33:16.000-04"
  at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:396)
  at com.dima.tests.DatesConversions.main(DatesConversions.java:24)
```

Please, help !!

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I am doing a middle man module.  I am dealing with input into my service, and output to another service.  Those were designed already, and not by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `ISO 8601 time zone` timezone, you have the use the below pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

And then, to get the date:

```
Date date = inFormatter.parse("2021-10-13 11:33:16.000-04");
```

Always check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Thanks.  It works perfectly.  That format - ""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX"", I could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Date as it is outdated. Use the classes in the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.htmlpackage)

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(str, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));       
System.out.println(odt);
```

Prints

```
2021-10-13T11:33:16-04:00
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Even though you need to give an old-fashionede `Date` object to a legacy API beyond your control, I still recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, in your own code. The final conversion to `Date` is pretty straight-forward.

I’d use this formatter for maximum reuse of existing formatters:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .appendOffset("+HHmm", "+00")
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

Then we parse and convert like this:

```
    String input = "2021-10-13 11:33:16.000-04";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, PARSER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    
    Instant i = dateTime.toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(i);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in my time zone, Europe/Copenhagen:

> ```
> 2021-10-13T11:33:16-04:00
> Wed Oct 13 17:33:16 CEST 2021
> ```

Denmark is at offset +02:00 at this time of year, so 6 hours ahead of the UTC offset -04 from your string. Therefore `Date.toString()` confusingly prints a clock hour that is 6 hours ahead of the original time of day.

Note: if your forward service accepts anything else than an old-fashioned `Date`, you should not be using that class. For example, if a `String` is required, the `OffsetDateTime` that we got can be formatted into a new string using a second `DateTimeFormatter` (or in lucky cases, its `toString` method).

### What went wrong in your code?

First, a UTC offset can have positive or negative sign. Instead of `-04` you could have had for example `+09`. Formatters are designed for to take the sign, `+` or `-`, as part of the offset. Therefore hardcoding the minus sign as a literal, as in your first attempt, is bound to fail. In your second attempt, `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`, you are already closer. However, `ZZ` is for an offset with sign and *four* digits (like `+0530` or `-0400`; hour and minute), so does not work for a two-digit offset like `-04`. Your `SimpleDateFormat` expected more digits where your string ended and therefore threw the exception that you saw.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.